# tf.transform: add preprocessing to Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a `keras` model for text classification using a `tensorflow` backend.  It currently assumes the input is a numpy array of integers.

I'd like to modify this so that I can train and predict on raw text.  From what I've gathered, this involves using `tf.transform` to convert a tensor of strings into a tensor of integers.

I've done this using `tf.transform` but now am unsure how to add this preprocessing step to my model as the very first layer / step.  To be clear, my input data looks like this:

`[{"review":"movie is great},
{"review":"awful film"}]`

and the output is:

`[{"review_out": array([-1, -1, 1, 0, 2])},
{"review_out": array([-1, -1, -1, 3, 4])]`

The function that does this is called `preprocess`.  So I just want to include running `preprocess` as the first step in my DAG.

How might I do this?

For reference, this is important because I want to do live prediction on ML Engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `tf.data.Dataset()`, there exists a `tf.data.Dataset().map(map_func)` function that allows you to apply `map_func` to all elements of your dataset. This could be used to add your preprocessing step.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

For example:

`dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))`

`dataset = dataset.map(preprocess)`

`model.fit(dataset, ....)`

There are other advantages to using `tf.data.Dataset()` over a numpy array as well.

Comment: thanks!  I'm using `tf.data.Dataset()`, but I need the preprocessing to be incorporated as the first step in the underlying Tensorflow DAG.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Note that if the preprocessing is not part of learning and/or it's heavy, you should do it separately to avoid bottleneck.

Comment: @THN But how would I ensure that the same preprocessing is done on ML Engine.  The goal is to be able to send ML Engine raw text

Comment: You only have to do it while learning if it were online learning on realtime stream data. In that case you should use asynchronous parallel processing to remedy the effects. It's called "pre"processing for a reason.

Comment: @THN Thanks for the help.  So is the standard way of doing this to perform preprocessing as JordanPatterson suggested and then update the `serving_fn` to also use this preprocessing?

Comment: I would say it depends on specific case. Most of the time you can and should do preprocessing before processing. Except for example you want to do some data transform on the fly like reading stream data/adding random noise/doing some random used-once operations. In this case you need to carefully optimize performance to avoid bottleneck, see [TF input performance guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance) for example.