# Keras Lambda Layer Before Embedding: Use to Convert Text to Integers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I currently have a `keras` model which uses an `Embedding` layer.  Something like this:

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(20,) dtype='int32')
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=1000,
                              output_dim=50,
                              input_length=20,
                              trainable=True,
                              embeddings_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                              mask_zero=False)(input)
```

This is great and works as expected.  However, I want to be able to send text to my model, have it preprocess the text into integers, and continue normally.

Two issues:

1) The Keras docs say that Embedding layers can only be used as the first layer in a model: https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/

2) Even if I could add a `Lambda` layer before the `Embedding`, I'd need it to keep track of certain state (like a dictionary mapping specific words to integers).  How might I go about this stateful preprocessing?

In short, I need to modify the underlying Tensorflow DAG, so when I save my model and upload to ML Engine, it'll be able to handle my sending it raw text.

Thanks!

Comment: This is basically the same question as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897995/tf-transform-add-preprocessing-to-keras-model) except with a different description. You still have not explained why you want to convert the text to integers inside the model during training rather than beforehand.

Comment: It sounds like from this description that your best course of action is to have an encoder and decoder function that is executed outside of training. You run the encoder on your dataset before sending it through your model, and you run the logits (output) of your model through the decoder to see what the predictions were.

Comment: @JordanPatterson I want to convert the text to integers inside the model during training so that when I upload the `saved_model.pb` to ML Engine, it will use the same preprocessing as was done in training.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the first few layers of a model which uses a string input:

```
input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string", name='input_1')
lookup_table_op = tf.contrib.lookup.index_table_from_tensor(
 mapping=vocab_list,
 num_oov_buckets=num_oov_buckets,
 default_value=-1,
)
lambda_output = Lambda(lookup_table_op.lookup)(input)
emb_layer = Embedding(int(number_of_categories),int(number_of_categories**0.25))(lambda_output)
```

Then you can continue the model as you normally would after an embedding layer. This is working for me and the model trains fine from string inputs.

It is recommended that you do the string -> int conversion in some preprocessing step to speed up the training process. Then after the model is trained you create a second keras model that just converts string -> int and then combine the two models to get the full string -> target model.